# i cant convert osm data to geojson with osm2geojson on python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, folium

there is a problem.
i have an xml file, which i get by writing content from https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/151234 (for example).
so i need to convert this xml file to geojson. After i will use it in GIS (folium).
I tied this.
but its dosent work at all

```
with codecs.open('ykt.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data:
    xml = data.read()

geojson = osm2geojson.xml2geojson(xml, filter_used_refs=False, log_level='INFO')
```

it returns a lot of warnings like:

```
Element not found in refs_index 'way' 551311593
Ref for way not found in index {'ref': 551311593, 'role': 'outer', 'type': 'way', 'used': 79374}
Failed to make way {'ref': 551311593, 'role': 'outer', 'type': 'way', 'used': 79374} in relation {'changeset': 127256102,
 'id': 79374,
 'members': [{'ref': 27504067, 'role': 'admin_centre', 'type': 'node'},
             {'ref': 573226686, 'role': 'label', 'type': 'node'},
             {'ref': 140262557, 'role': 'inner', 'type': 'way', 'used': 79374},
             {'ref': 140262579, 'role': 'inner', 'type': 'way', 'used': 79374},
             {'ref': 547974388, 'role': 'inner', 'type': 'way', 'used': 79374},...
```

and finally i get an empty result in geojson. which shows nothing on folium map.
how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/151234 doesn't return any geometry information. If you need geometry information then append `/full` to your URL: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/151234/full

See the [OSM API documentatin](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Full:_GET_/api/0.6/%5Bway%7Crelation%5D/#id/full) for more information.

Comment: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/151234/full.json
without .json request returns nothing. 
but still there are troublues with geojson. Now its not empty, but i cant say that its with rigt data. 
when i try to draw this geojson on the map its look glithed. not like normal boundaries

Comment: Well, not sure what your particular problem is. OSM doesn't return GeoJSON so you must have used some converter. Maybe this converter does something wrong?